# Proper way to empty semaphore property after initialization usage

Tags: c#, semaphore, lazy-initialization

I'm using the following c# code to initialize some properties:

```
class MyClass
{        
    private static readonly string _myLuaScript = "..."; 
    private SemaphoreSlim _myLuaScriptSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    private LoadedLuaScript? _myLoadedLuaScript = null;

    public async Task<LoadedLuaScript> GetMyLoadedLuaScript
    {
        if (_myLoadedLuaScript == null)
        {
            await _myLuaScriptSemaphore.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                if (_myLoadedLuaScript == null)
                {
                    _myLoadedLuaScript = await LoadAsync();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _myLuaScriptSemaphore.Release();
            }
        }
        return _myLoadedLuaScript;
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I properly get rid of `_myLuaScriptSemaphore`, since there is a point where I no longer need it.
Ideally, I would want to use a struct/class `Loader` to handle this logic, but I can't seem to see a way that elegantly does not leave something allocated behind.

Bonus question, but I don't I don't think it's nicely doable, is there a way to somehow return a `LoadedLuaScript` after the initialization stage ?

Comment: Are you using a semaphore to effectively manage a lazy loaded singleton? If so, maybe you would be better off replacing it with an [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asynclazyt/)

Comment: probably unrelated but what's the reasoning for doing ```await semaphore.WaitAsync()``` instead of just ```semaphore.Wait()```

Comment: @LampToast I figure I would want to not block the execution. Plus it makes senss to use it with LoadAsync, so this seemed to make sense to me. Am I missing something ? Is it overkill ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes indeed. Thanks, it seems like AsyncLazy is what I'm looking for.